# Give a custom file name to each file being zipped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am downloading multiple files from S3 and zipping them. How do I give a custom name to each file being zipped?

```
def download_all_files
   folder_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/downloads/"
   zipfile_name = "#{Rails.root}/public/archive.zip"

   FileUtils.remove_dir(folder_path) if Dir.exist?(folder_path)
   FileUtils.remove_entry(zipfile_name) if File.exist?(zipfile_name)
   Dir.mkdir("#{Rails.root}/public/downloads")

   @model_object.each do |attachment|
      open(folder_path + "#{attachment.avatar.file.filename}", 'wb') do |file|
         file << open("#{attachment.avatar.url}").read
      end
   end

   input_filenames = Dir.entries(folder_path).select {|f| !File.directory? f}

   Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
      input_filenames.each do |attachment|
         zipfile.add(attachment,File.join(folder_path,attachment))
      end
   end

   send_file(File.join("#{Rails.root}/public/", 'archive.zip'), :type => 'application/zip', :filename => "#{Time.now.to_date}.zip")

end
```

Comment: what name are you looking in place of archive.zip??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have 2 ways you can accomplish this. To the end user, both of these should yield the same result, just depends how you want them on your server.

#### 1. Change it while zipping the files together

This will leave the files as they are currently named on your system and only change them in the output archive.zip

Looking at this [gem](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#basic-zip-archive-creation) it looks like

> ```
> Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
>   input_filenames.each do |filename|
>     # Two arguments:
>     # - The name of the file as it will appear in the archive
>     # - The original file, including the path to find it
>     zipfile.add(filename, folder + '/' + filename)
>   end
>   zipfile.get_output_stream("myFile") { |os| os.write "myFile contains just this" }
> end
> ```

So, in your code just change the first occurrence of 'attachment' on

```
zipfile.add(attachment, File.join(folder_path, attachment))
```

to whatever you want the name to be.

#### 2. Change it while writing the file to your server

Since you are writing the file just a few lines above there

```
open(folder_path + "#{attachment.avatar.file.filename}", 'wb') do |file|
```

you could change the file name on this line as well. This would change the filename on your server and in the archive.zip